# Why doesn't need to malloc struct tm pointer before call localtime() function?

Tags: c++, pointers, localtime

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    time_t nowTime;
    struct tm *nowStruct;

    time(&nowTime);

    nowStruct = localtime(&nowTime);
    cout << nowStruct->tm_hour << ":" << nowStruct->tm_min << endl;
}
```

I suspect that where is the address of memory used to store struct tm.

Answer (score 3):

`localtime` uses an internal, global buffer (or perhaps thread-local), whose address it returns. This practice of keeping a global state around is similar to how `strtok` and `rand` work. Note that this makes the function inherently non-rentrant, and perhaps thread-unsafe.

Comment: To add to that, to cite the manpage on my system: _"The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions."_